# How can I send a message to a buffer and print the message with the first three words in reverse?

Tags: c++, awk, operating-system, pipe

I want the folowing message: "This is a message to buffer" to be printed as : "a is This message to buffer". I know I must use `awk` , but im not very sure of how I can do this...

Here is code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE *fpo;              //for writing to a pipe

    char buffer[BUFSIZ+1];      //BUFSIZ defined in <stdio.h>



    //Write buffer a message
    sprintf(buffer, "This is a message to buffer\n");  

    fpo = popen ( "od -c", "w" );   //pipe to command "od -c"
                    //od -- output dump, see "man od"
    if ( fpo != NULL ) 
    {
        //send data from buffer to pipe 
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), fpo );  
        pclose ( fpo );             //close the pipe
        return 0; 
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The following is the output of this program:

```
luisgeesb@luisgeesb-pc:~/460/lab4$ g++ -o pipe2 pipe2.cpp
luisgeesb@luisgeesb-pc:~/460/lab4$ ./pipe2
0000000   T   h   i   s       i   s       a       m   e   s   s   a   g
0000020   e       t   o       b   u   f   f   e   r  \n
0000034
```

Essentially I want something like:

```
luisgeesb@luisgeesb-pc:~/460/lab4$ g++ -o pipe2 pipe2.cpp
luisgeesb@luisgeesb-pc:~/460/lab4$ ./pipe2
0000000   a       i   s       T   h   i   s       m   e   s   s   a   g
0000020   e       t   o       b   u   f   f   e   r  \n
0000034
```

Comment: Is using awk a requirement? Otherwise read the text into a `std::vector<std::string>>`, use `std::reverse` on a part of  the `vector`, and then output it again.

Comment: Thats what I had in mind is just to reverse the string before i write the message to the buffer, but I was wondering if this could be done with AWK.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "This is a message to buffer" | awk '{t=$1;$1=$3;$3=t}1'

a is This message to buffer
```

note that reversing odd number elements will keep the center in place.  That's why here there is no need to change second field.

Comment: Yessss. i totally understand that. I think this will work for me.